# ubuntu 14.04 64bit and vlc 2.1.4 screensaver keeps coming on

Tags: unity, vlc, screensaver

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit running vlc 2.1.4, using unity desktop and xscreensaver installed from the Software Center. (Gnome screen-saver is not installed.)

Whenever I play a video in fullscreen in vlc the screensaver comes on.  I have the option **inhibit the power management daemon during playback** checked and **disable screesaver** checked, but the screensaver still comes on.  I upgraded from 13.10 64-bit Ubuntu and uninstalled vlc and reinstalled it but the screensaver still comes on.

I reset my vlc config file by deleting it and starting vlc again to recreate.

http://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html
Linux / Unix: $(HOME)/.config/vlc/vlcrc (v0.9.0 and above),

Comment: are you still looking for help with this problem?